# Capacitor Release APK is Not Getting Installed | Ionic App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor

I have just started working with capacitor ionic, I have created a simple app. When I run the app using android studio, it is working fine but when I create a release apk, it says install failed.

I am trying to copy the apk-release and trying to install it on another phone. Is it wrong? I just want to confirm that the apk is working fine.

I usually notice the below error in Logcat

```
2021-02-19 03:21:02.226 671-671/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
2021-02-19 03:21:02.494 21232-21281/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
2021-02-19 03:21:02.987 21317-21317/? E/dboxed_process: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getCurrentAuthType sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.012 1890-1890/? E/MiuiFaceFactory: getFaceManager sCurrentAuthType = 1
2021-02-19 03:21:03.168 1612-2571/? E/FingerprintService: Stopping background authentication, top: com.google.android.packageinstaller currentClient: com.miui.securitycenter
```

**variable.gradle**

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.1.0'
    androidxCoreVersion =  '1.2.0'
    androidxMaterialVersion =  '1.1.0-rc02'
    androidxBrowserVersion =  '1.2.0'
    androidxLocalbroadcastmanagerVersion =  '1.0.0'
    androidxExifInterfaceVersion = '1.2.0'
    firebaseMessagingVersion =  '20.1.2'
    playServicesLocationVersion =  '17.0.0'
    junitVersion =  '4.12'
    androidxJunitVersion =  '1.1.1'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion =  '3.2.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion =  '7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you sign the apk?? Because an apk can't be installed on a device without signing it

Comment: If you're trying to test the release bundle, why don't you create an .aab file and then release it for internal testing through the google play store console. That would be a much better testing flow.